# Forcibly show previous/next links

Tags: navigation

I want to design the previous/next links on a fresh WP install with only the one single post but cannot see them and therefore cannot control my design.

How can I force WP to show the page navigation when there are not enough posts for more than one page?

I do not want to publish a series of placeholder posts.

Comment: Why would you not use the Theme Test data? Any reason not choosing the placeholder posts?

Comment: Set yourself up with a proper local test install and then download and install [this package](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Unit_Test)

Comment: @ManojKumar I'm not happy with pu lishing fake posts because Google is crawling my domain every hour and the placeholders will appear in my search results.

Comment: @PieterGoosen Thanks a lot. I never even knew this existed.

Comment: Better work on local environment and then push the changes to live server.

Comment: Every developer should have a local test install, it is a great playground to stuff around with ideas and what is really great, it takes 10 seconds to fix if you break your local site due to a php error. I personally use XAMPP on windows 7, but there are plenty more out there for all platforms. Just hit google :-)

Comment: I'm not a developer. I just design my blog this once. Setting up a test install would take more time than I have. Blogging is just a hobby for me. But thanks. I'll use the test data and then remove the results from Google again, if they appear there.

Comment: Just set the option in back end then that your site should not be crawled, or download and install a maintenance plugin

Answer (score 0):

What I did was the following:

1. Look in index.php for the name of the function that creates the older/newer posts links.
2. Search (using the multifile search function of my text editor) for where that function is defined.
3. Open that file and copy the HTML code from there to index.php, replacing the function call.
4. Save index.php (but not close the file).
5. Style the links.
6. Replace the faux HTML code with the original function code again in index.php (since I left the file open in my text editor I only had to click "Undo" once and then save).
7. Done.

Took me a few minutes.